# Set Session inside the javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to set session inside the javascript. But all the time this function return false value. Please tell me the error of this code.

```
<script>
function myFunction(){

var r=confirm("Would you like to add another item ?");
if (r==true) {
    alert('ok');
    var varname = '<?php echo $_SESSION["redirect"]=1; ?>';     
 } 

 if(r==false)   {
     alert('bad');
    var varname = '<?php echo $_SESSION["redirect"]=2; ?>';
 }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't set a session inside Javascript

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan He can if it's a PHP file masquerading as a JS file.

Comment: @Danny That's still setting the session value in PHP, you just changed the extension of the file. That's not the same as "setting a session in Javascript".

Comment: The difference between sessions and cookies is that sessions are stored _Server-Side_. It stands to reason they can't be set _client-side_

Answer (score 1):

You can't evaluate PHP on the client. Do an AJAX request to the server setting the session variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client side, so you'll need to perform an AJAX call to a server side script that will change the sessions value.

Something in the lines of:

```
function changeSession()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: /change_session.php?value=1&key=redirect,
        dataType:"html"
    });
}
```

And in change_session.php:

```
<?php $_SESSION[$_REQUEST['key']]=$_REQUEST['value'] ?>
```